# Is it possible to estimate the cumulative effect without using distributed lag model?

Tags: r, time-series, poisson-regression, lags, distributed-lag

I am fitting the temperature and mortality data by using conditional Poisson regression. The following formula and data are used:

https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-14-122

```
gnm(numdeaths ~ ozone10 + temperature_lag1, data=q, family=poisson,       
                eliminate=factor(stratum))
```

In this formula, the lagged effect is estimated by inputting `temperature_lag1` to the formula. However, the cumulative effect (0-1 lags) cannot be estimated. Is there anyway to estimate it? Or did I miss any assumption of the conditional Poisson regression?